# MaterialComponents >1.0.0 reverts back to AppCompat

Tags: android, material-components

I tried MaterialComponents `1.0.0` in my app to use the outlined text box design. Everything was fine, but I also wanted to use the `startIconDrawable` property. It turned out, that I had to update to at least `1.1.0` to do so. I did, but since the update, the whole design reverted back to the AppCompat style.

### Here are some code

**build.gradle (app module)**

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
}
```

EDIT: Also tried `1.1.0-beta01`.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
...
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/registerDate"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/date"nt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/outline_calendar_today_24">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/registerDateField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date" />
...
```

**Expected**

[image]

**Actual**

[image]

Comment: Try using version 1.1.0-beta01 instead of version 1.2.0-alpha01

Comment: I've tried that too. Sorry, I left it out of the post.

Comment: It is quite strange. Does the activity use the AppTheme theme? Also the buttons are very strange.

Comment: Yes, it does use the AppTheme. And with MaterialComponent 1.0.0 it looks like on the first screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to recreate the project from scratch, and everything is fine now.

I post this answer, because I've had other, seemingly unrelated issues, and several answers to those said that cleaning the cache in Android Studio solves them.

I have not tried to solve this one with cleaning the cache, but it **might** work.